# BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null occasionally

Tags: android

I ran into the following problem. I have big images in my assets folder. When users first open the app I optimize these images for their device and cache it to SD.

I open the file from assets using:

```
stream = getResources().getAssets().open("assetName");
```

Which I wrap in BufferedInputStream

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(stream, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Then I just decode the image with BitmapFactory and do all the stuff with result. Well, I actually used to pass inSampleSize for smaller devices, but then I opted for storing half size version of the image along with fullsize, because it greatly improves image decode speed (I suspect due to IO operations).

The problem I have is that I am receiving exceptions (rare, but still) that `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` returns null for them. I don't understand why. Reports I had were from Android 4.0.3 galaxy note users, which is powerfull enough to keep around 4 Mb of image data obviously. So I doubt this is OOM, or "exeeds VM budget". If assets were missing, `getAssets().open(...)` would probably throw exception.

Then what? Have anyone ran into the similar issue?

Thanks.

Comment: i think it will work if the image is added in web view

Comment: I think I'm hitting the same problem. It happens rarely on scattered devices in the field, but the same app version will work for 99% of folks. Opening a large bitmap in assets, lots of process JVM memory unused, no exception it just returns null. Verified the input stream is non-null and pointing to the correct asset. I'm investigating

Comment: I'm noticing a pattern, I've had 6 errors reported today, every device was running 2.3.4. I've seen posts talking about BitmapFactory decoder  bugs, maybe this version has a problem. (It's loading a large png)